# Parse html with lxml (tag h3)

Tags: python, html, parsing, xpath, lxml

I'm trying to parse some html and I have some problem with this little html code.

*XML:*

```xml
<div>
    <p><span><a href="../url"></a></span></p>
    <h3 class="header"><a href="../url">Other</a></h3>
    <a href="../url">Other</a><br>
    <a class="aaaaa" href="../url">Indice</a>
    <p></p>               
</div>
```

*code:*

```
import urllib
from lxml import etree
import StringIO
resultado=urllib.urlopen('trozo.html')
html = resultado.read()
parser= etree.HTMLParser()
tree=etree.parse(StringIO.StringIO(html),parser)
xpath='/div/h3'
html_filtrado=tree.xpath(xpath)
print html_filtrado
```

When I print the code it appears [], and I suppose that It should be a list with `<h3 class="header"><a href="../url">Other</a></h3>` in it.
If I would have that list I would execute etree.tostring(html_filtrado) to see `<h3 class="header"><a href="../url">Other</a></h3>`.

So how can get this code?

```
<h3 class="header"><a href="../url">Other</a></h3>
```

Or only `../url` ? which is the part I want!!

Thank you

Comment: what you posted is **not** XML compliant, `<br>` without a closing tag is illegal XML, `lxml` is first and for most an XML parsing library, to enable broken HTML you need to set some flags on the parser. Try using an HTML parser instead or convert your HTML to XHTML.

Comment: But I have parse a lot of pages without problem, with <br>!! So, what flags I need to use? Because I really like this parser, it's really fast!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The case is, that etree.HTMLParser() when receives HTML, it creates the full html DOM tree.
So, instead of what you intended, if you use etree.tostring(tree) you get

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><div>
<p><span><a href="../url"/></span></p>
<h3 class="header"><a href="../url">Other</a></h3>
<a href="../url">Other</a><br/><a class="aaaaa" href="../url">Indice</a>
<p/>
```

So, the correct xpath would be '/html/body/div/h3'

Comment: It doesn't work! :( This is a part of a big document and xpath is '/html/body/......./div/h3'. And it doesn't work. It's a problem with h3. Because I can read until div. And then it doen't reconize h3 tag.

Comment: Could you please sample the whole document? Obviously, the part is not enough to find out what's the problem with your structure. Of course, you can stick to the second answer on this question, but it's not optimal :) Or, in fact, the case may be that HTMLParser() by default fixes the broken HTML, so if it's broken and then fixed, it could contain extra HTML tags, try using to_string() and looking at the structure again.

Answer (score 4):

The XPath query in your example is not quite right.

To get a list of all `h3` tags within `div` tags, you should use this:

```
elements = tree.xpath('//div/h3')
etree.tostring(elements[0])
```

Which should give:

```
'<h3 class="header"><a href="../url">Other</a></h3>\n'
```

To get a list of all `href` attributes of `a` tags within `h3` tags, you could use something like this:

```
tree.xpath('//h3/a/@href')
```

Which gives:

```
['../url']
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! That works for me!! I think that I have to learn more about xpath. Thank you